# Do card Members get notified of all comments automatically?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I find it cumbersome to have to @mention someone every time I want them to know that I commented on a card (especially when there are only two of us on a board). I added the person as a "Member" to the card - but not sure if they are getting notifications without using @mention.

If the answer to the question is "no", then can someone recommend a more streamlined way of ensuring board members get notified of cards they are Members of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, members (and also "watchers") of a card get notified for comments, due date changes and card moves.

This info is on the Trello help at [Watching cards, lists, and boards](https://help.trello.com/article/799-watching-cards-lists-and-boards).

Comment: Thanks that article helped!